# What to do with <supportedRuntime> in app.config in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When using **.Net Framework** we had the following lines in `app.config`:

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
</startup>
```

I'm wondering what should we do with these lines when porting to **.NET Core**?

Should we remove them or replace them with something else?

Comment: Did you try running it on a non-Windows machine? I guess it is just ignored.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, No I haven't tried it. Can I safely assume that it is not needed anymore?

Comment: Well there is no app.config in .NET Core so yeah.

Comment: It seems that `app.config` won't contain any logic in dotnet core and it only serves as an XML config source and will not affect **how** the application works anymore.
BTW, I closed my own question as a duplicate, so proud of myself ^^